# Why is my JDBCBrokerFactory growing

Tags: java, jpa, memory-leaks, openjpa

We are using OpenJPA 2.3.0 (before 2.2.0 with same problems) connected to a DB2 database in a WAS environment (8.5) with Spring to some degree.
The problem we have is that the application keeps eating more and more memory until it eventually crashes.

When using the (by many) recommended Memory Analyzer Tool we get one culprit the JDBCBrokerFactory.
It has a ConcurrentHashMap (with 16 entries) that given the usage numbers is responsible for the lost memory.
(Max memory 1024M, after 10 hours of contionous but not too rough load this class is responsible for 400M and the only pointed out by MAT)

That a factory class is held by the environment (org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator and com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper) is not surprising to me but I would expect the class not to grow or at least shrink better when needed. (In JPA 2.2.0 there were many more classes retaining this class, still none of "our" classes)

Of course this class in not one of the classes we interact with (internals of the OpenJPA implementation) which makes it harder to see were we err in using JPA.

Any ideas or hint on what we could improve to limit the havoc from JDBCBrokerFactory would be very much appreciated.

/Martin

Answer (score 0):

If your code stores stuff in a Map, if you don't want the map to continually grow, you eventually need to remove items from the Map.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that connections are not getting cleaned up properly in your application. That's why this map is growing indefinitely. I would suggest you to clean the connections properly manually or use proper integration of JPA with spring, as spring will take care of it by itself..

Comment: We do not manage any connections manually, for custom queries we use JPA so we don't have anything that we CAN close.
Hopefully our JPA-xml-configuration is in order, we don't do a lot of fancy stuff here either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application is properly cleaning up it's EntityManagers. Be sure to close an EntityManager when you are done using it.

Comment: We only use injected EntityManagers so I cannot see them as the source of the leak unforunately.